# Java with Hibernate Database

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have code which updates a column in a database which looks like this:

```
logger.info("Entering Update Method");
        Query query =session.createQuery("update CardMaster cm set cm.otpAmount = :otpAmount" + " where cm.cardNumber = :cardnumber");
        double otpAmount= cardMaster.getOtpAmount();
        String cardNumber=cardMaster.getCardNumber();
        query.setParameter("otpAmount",otpAmount);
        query.setParameter("cardnumber",cardNumber);
        query.executeUpdate();
        logger.info("cardMasterUpdated successfully");
```

In this I am getting otpamount ,cardnumber and it is giving result of executeupdate as 1 but it is not reflecting in Database .. I am opening the session and committing correctly outside.

Instead of using this, if I  use `update()` of hibernate it is happening correctly.

Can you help me out of this?

Comment: you didn't commit transaction

Answer (score 0):

You have to commit the transaction.

Since you do not commit, nothing is visible for other processes, like the tool you are using to view your DB.

You can acquire your transaction with `session.getTransaction()`. However, normally you start your transaction manually like this:

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
// Do your stuff
session.flush();
tx.commit()
```

Comment: don't forget a session.flush() as well before you commit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i made a logical mistake and that was the problem :( and i am commiting the traxns correclty outside :)